# Error when using autofocus on an input element (Reactjs)

Tags: html, reactjs

I have the following element

```
<textarea className='title' autofocus="autoFocus" 
   onChange={(e)=>changeBill(e, 'title')} 
   value={bill?.title} 
   placeholder="Bill Title">
</textarea>
```

When I open the browser, it gives the following warning:

> Warning: Invalid DOM property `autofocus`. Did you mean `autoFocus`?

It's still working, but the warning is pretty annoying.
I tried "autofocus" and "autoFocus" neither prevents the warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is not about the value of the property, but the property name itself. It should be:

```
<textarea className='title' autoFocus={true} 
   onChange={(e)=>changeBill(e, 'title')} 
   value={bill?.title} 
   placeholder="Bill Title">
</textarea>
```

Also the property is accepting `true` or `false`. In your example the non empty string is interpreted as `true`.